# Is there a way to change the value of React uncontrolled component?

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form, yup

I'm using React18, react-hook-form, yup to make my application and developing a data bulk register feature. Here is a feature process I have to develop.

1. User upload a excel file
2. Application parses that excel file
3. Put the parsed data in every inputs
4. User can edit data that they uploaded in input component
5. When user typing, value like price must be changed formatted value (like user typed 1000, then value changed 1,000)

There are more than 10 cells in a row and also may be many rows depending on the file that user uploads, so I implemented uncontrolled input component, not controlled component.
But I knew that uncontrolled component handle data by the DOM itself and I can't format the value unlike controlled component.
I also used yup resolver transform, but it changed the value after call handleSubmit function.

I'm wondering

1. Is there a way to format the value of React uncontrolled component when user is typing.
2. Is there a better way to control many inputs at once without rendering issue.
   Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

you could use useRef if the re-rendering worries you

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please edit to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.